# How to show that $x_n = \frac{n+1}{\log_2{(n+1)}}$ is unbounded without calculus?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

I want to prove the problem below without using calculus.

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \frac{n+1}{\log_2{(n+1)}}
> $$
>   Show that $x_n$ is unbounded.

I've started with comparing $x_{n-1}$ and $x_n$. Suppose $x_{n-1} > x_n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n}{\log_2n} &> \frac{n+1}{\log_2(n+1)} \iff \\
\iff n\log_2{(n+1)} &>(n+1)\log_2n \\
\log_2(n+1)^{n} &>\log_2n^{n+1} \\
\log_2(n+1)^{n} &> \log_2n + \log_2n^{n} \\
\log_2(n+1)^{n} - \log_2n^{n} &>\log_2n \\
\log_2\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n} &> \log_2n
\end{align}
$$

This is only true for $n=1$. Since $\left(1 + {1\over n}\right)^n$ is bounded by:

$$
\log_2{2} <\left(1 + {1\over n}\right)^n < \log_23
$$

and $\log_2n$ is unbounded we may conclude that $\{ \forall n > 1 : x_{n+1} > x_n\}$

But this only proves that the sequence is increasing starting from $n=2$. (It is actually $1+\sqrt5 \over 2$ if $n \in \mathbb R$). Since an increasing sequence is not necessarily unbounded the above doesn't solve what's in the problem statement.

Given $x_n$ is monotonically increasing starting from $n=2$ can we somehow prove it is unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $n=2^k-1$ and $k\geq 2$,
$$\frac{n+1}{\log_2{(n+1)}}=\frac{2^k}{k}=\frac{(1+1)^k}{k}\geq \frac{\binom{k}{2}}{k}= \frac{k-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $\frac{z}{\log_2 z}$ is unbounded as $z\to +\infty$, or that $\frac{2^w}{w}$ is unbounded as $w\to +\infty.$ 
On the other hand, assuming $w\geq 2$,
$$ 2^w = \left(2^{w/2}\right)^2 \geq \left(1+\frac{w}{2}\right)^2 = 1+w+\frac{w^2}{4}$$
hence the last claim is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M\ge 5$ then

$$\frac{n+1}{\log_2{(n+1)}} \ge M \iff n+1 \ge M\cdot \log_2{(n+1)}$$

and for $n+1\ge 2^M$

$$2^M\ge  M\cdot \log_2{2^M}=M^2$$

wich is true.